# Facebook User Birthday as java.util.Date

Tags: java, android, facebook

This may seen like a trivial question but I need to get it answered. When you access the Facebook user's date of birth, it seems to return it as a string conforming to dd/mm/yy format. Does it always return it that way? And what's best way to parse that string to a Java date object in the util package?

Comment: For your second question, look at Java's `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to the Date class in java.util, I would suggest using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

That said, you could then parse the date with something like:

```
DateTime.parse(yourDate, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yy"))
```

I'm not positive about Facebook's API, but this should help you parse that nonetheless.

EDIT: for using the java.util.Date class

As Mr. David Wallace suggested, SimpleDateFormat, is likely what you want.

```
Date date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
try {
    date = sdf.parse("30/12/90");
    System.out.println(date.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

Edit 2: Facebook date format
It appears that Facebook uses the format MM/DD/YYYY for birthdays via its API. [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

Comment: I use Joda Time for my server side jobs but for Android, the inclusion of the API will increase the size of the app. Hence, it makes sense to use the APIs that Android provides out of the box.

Comment: Understood. Answer edited to accommodate use of java Date class.

Comment: THanks. That solves my date conversion problem though I'll have to experiment by myself to answer my first question.

Comment: On a side note: the given link in post refers to FQL (as of right now, GraphAPI is preffered, as it's newer, and can be more powerful): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user Given here,  birthday is not as easy to parse, as given code, so be careful.